# POCO json POST_METHOD returns results but gives I/O exception and ends program

Tags: c++, post, ssl, https, poco-libraries

Hi im havng a problem with poco under linux, im making a https json post to a webserver and im getting the response as i expected.
The problem is that i get an error after the response is printed and it ends the execution of my program.

Here is what i get on console:

```
200 OK

"{\"test_results\": ["result1", "result2", "result3", "result4"]}"

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Poco::IOException'  what():  I/O error
```

Here is the code that make the above result to be printed:

```
int posTry(){
try
  {
    // prepare session
    Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_NONE, 9, false, "ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH");

    Poco::URI uri("https://someURL/somePATH");
    Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), context);

    // prepare path
    std::string path(uri.getPathAndQuery());
    if (path.empty()) path = "/";

    // send request
    std::string test = "{Some json code to get results that is already working}";

    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, path, Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
    req.setContentType("application/json");
    req.setKeepAlive(true);
    req.setContentLength( test.length() );

    session.sendRequest(req) << test;

    // get response
    Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;
    std::cout << res.getStatus() << " " << res.getReason() << std::endl;

    // print response
    std::istream &is = session.receiveResponse(res);
    Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(is, std::cout);
    std::vector<Poco::Net::HTTPCookie> cookies;
    res.getCookies( cookies );
  }
catch( const Poco::Exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.displayText() << std::endl;
    }
  catch (...)
    {
      std::cout << "error";
      return -1;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I don't know what is this error about and I can't even catch the error in (...) and make the program continue. Can someone help me?

Comment: Use Fiddler to inspect the response. Possibly the Content-Length header is incorrect or a cookie is malformed.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so could you post it? If not... it seems weird that you print the response before you get the response... despite what your code comments say :-)

Answer (score 0):

The exception comes from the destructor of Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession,

This is a known bug fixed in POCO release 1.4.2.

source: http://pocoproject.org/docs/99100-ReleaseNotes.html

If you cannot upgrade, you should be able to get rid of the exception by adding a specific catch for it.